# SQL How to Make A Column Delimited Into One Line

Tags: sql

i was wondering how would i make a sql code that makes one column merge into one line

please see attached photo of an example table of before and after of what i need

can this be done

any help will be appreciated

thanks
[HERE IS THE IMAGE OF WHAT I NEED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzAqG.jpg)

Comment: Can you put the data of the image in text format? Do you want the first column (Title) to keep its old length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Rather than images, use formatted text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in mySQL or mariaDB, `STRING_AGG()` in SQL server, Oracle or Postgres.
Here is an example in mySQL:

> ```
> create table examples(
> id int,
> example varchar(10));
> insert into examples values
> (1,'Example 1'),
> (2,'Example 2'),
> (3,'Example 3'),
> (4,'Example 4');
> ```

> ```
> select group_concat(example) Examples
> from examples;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Examples                                |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | Example 1,Example 2,Example 3,Example 4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c21f75df7d8176638c3e5461beb5e1c8)*

Comment: how would i then put this to result into a column as the result shows but i wanted the result to go into a coulmn

Comment: What are all the values in the row of title 1? I could use a sub-query to join the rows and only show them for 1 but if my logic is not what you want it will not be useful to you.